# Is the stabilization of a simple $C^*$-algebra simple?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Recall that a $C^*$-algebra is called *simple* if it has no non-trivial closed two-sided ideals.

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the $C^*$-algebra of compact operators on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$.

**Question:** It true that a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is simple if and only if the tensor product $A\otimes\mathcal{K}$ is simple?

*Thoughts:* One direction is obvious, since if $I$ is a non-trivial ideal in $A$, then $I\otimes\mathcal{K}$ is an ideal in $A\otimes\mathcal{K}$. What can be said about the converse?

Comment: Depending on what you know about the tensor product of $C^*$-algebras, I wouldn't call either direction obvious. You have to argue that $I \otimes \mathcal{K}$ is a non-trivial ideal of $A \otimes \mathcal{K}$ if $I$ is non-trivial, and nothing in your attempt says anything about this (never mind my comment if this is obvious to you though).

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think about that. I thought this would be a property of tensor products of algebras over $\mathbb{C}$. Would you mind elaborating a bit, to illustrate the difficulty?

Comment: Another relevant fact that can be used to prove your conjecture is that every (two-sided, closed) ideal of $A\otimes K$ is of the form $I\otimes K$, where $I$ is an ideal in $A$.

Comment: @geometricK There can not really happen odd things, but that's something that you should think about first. For example, did you actually prove that $I\otimes K\subseteq A\otimes K$? Proving this in itself already has some subtle things.

Comment: @Ruy Any hints how I could prove this directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be $C^*$-algebras. By a result of Takesaki, $A\otimes B$ (minimal tensor product) is simple iff $A$ and $B$ are simple (reference: chapter IV in Takesaki's first book).

Since the algebra of compact operators is simple, it follows that the answer to your question is positive.